# Vue-resource not recognize in project

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-resource

I'm using vue-resource in index.js, also I have installed package. But $http.get not working.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld'

Vue.use(VueResource)
Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
 routes: [
  { 
   path: '/',
   name: 'HelloWorld',
   component: HelloWorld
 }
]})
```

HelloWorld.vue

```
created: () => {
  console.log('run');
  this.$http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
    .then((response) => {
      this.posts = response.data;
      console.log(this.newUser);
    });
}
```

[image: vuejs]

Comment: Do not use an arrow function to define `created`.

Comment: @Bert Thank you buddy! Why vue not understand arrow function?

Comment: It's not that Vue doesn't understand arrow functions, the problem with using an arrow function define `this` as the context in which the arrow function is defined, which, before the component is created, is *not* the component.

Comment: Thank you Bert...